# Dragging Buttons to CollectionView (Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, storyboard

I am trying to use a collection view for my buttons. So, in the storyboard I took 8 buttons and added it into the collection view. The collection view has 8 cells for each button w/ 8 unique identifiers. All buttons show when I added it onto the Collection View.

But my problem is that when I build and run, I get no error however the 8 buttons in the cell do not show at all!

I didn't do any code in the background. Just drag and drop and used the attributes.

So I'm a bit confused as to why it's not showing. I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Did you control drag from the collection view to the vc to set up the delegates and data source?  You should also have your vc conform to the collection view delegate methods.

Comment: @Douglas: Yes, I did. I did some more research and I did forget to do that so thank you! But I have multiple cells with different identifiers (I cannot use one identifier) so it's only showing me one cell right now.

Comment: In your cellforindexpath method you most likely specified one reuse identifier. If you have 8 different cell types, you will need to figure out the order and use an if statement. If index path is 1 use cell with identifier "firstcell". If index path is 2 use another and so on.

Comment: @Douglas: Yes, I'm trying something along that. Here's my issue:

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "homeButton", for: indexPath)
        return cell

    }` That only prints one button. But I have another button with another ID so I'm not sure how to pull that.

Comment: Did you subclass your collection view cells?

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now so I can't post any code. But tomorrow I can. But look into subclassing. Then at the end of the let cell = line you use as! Your cell. I did the same thing with mult cells in a table view and can show you some code.

Comment: No, I did not use a subClass. I followed your way method and got it!

Comment: Sounds good. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me go ahead and use @Douglas's comment to answer the question. So first thing I completely forgot to do was to **ctrl + drag** the **Collection View** to the **ViewController** in the Storyboard and enable *dataSource* and *delegate*. Then in my ViewController.swift I implemented the following code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if(indexPath.item == 0) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "kitchenButton", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    } else if(indexPath.item == 1) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cameraButton", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    } else if(indexPath.item == 2) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "eventsButton", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    } else if(indexPath.item == 3) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "mapButton", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    } else if(indexPath.item == 4) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "journeyButton", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    } else if(indexPath.item == 5) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "callButton", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    } else if(indexPath.item == 6) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "handsButton", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    } else if(indexPath.item == 7) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "swimButton", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "none", for: indexPath)
            return cell
    }


}
```

The following code is for multiple cells. I am trying to achieve a horizontal scroll effect so this method worked beautifully for me.

Make sure to include *UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource* into the header of your class.

Thank you @Douglas!